# Fitting a large image to a specific size

Tags: css, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a series of images of different size (call it set A) that I am arranging next to each other. Upon press of a button, those images get replaced by a much larger image in original size. I'd like to make sure the replaced image adheres to the original image size. I've tried to apply various container width tricks, but so far have failed.

**I've set up a runnable demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-au2pcv** (code is in `home.html` and `home.ts` in pages directory)

If you press the "Switch" button, the images get replaced, as does the size (which I want to avoid)

(please excuse inline CSS styling)

The code:

My template

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div *ngFor="let image of images">
   <!-- the reason for this div is to force the placeholder image to this size -->
   <!-- doesn't seem to work... -->
   <div [ngStyle]="{'width':image.w, 'height':image.h, 'float':left}">
   <img [src]="showImage?image.src:placeholder" style="float:left;max-width:100%; max-height:100%;width:auto;height:auto;" />
   </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">
   <button ion-button (click)="toggleImage()">switch</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

The TS:

```
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
images = [{
    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200/',
    w:300,
    h:200,
  },
  {
    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
    w:100,
    h:100,
  },
  {
    src: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/80/',
    w:200,
    h:80,
  }];

  placeholder = "http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000";

  showImage:boolean = true;

  toggleImage() {
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
  }
```

Comment: Can you do a simple draw of what you have before and what you want after please. To be sur of what you are looking for.

Comment: Your image does not show in your demo

Answer (score 0):

Your demo doesn't show images. Anyways, to acheive this, you don't have to use containers and all other things. It can be acheive by using simple css. Before doing this, make sure to fix the size of the image. for example if you want the 1 image size to be 30% and height 100% and then set object-fit property of the css to be cover. Below is the quick example:-

```css
.image{
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="../image_path" class="image"/>
```

Thanks